# UILabel Text Code

Tags: swift

I am new to programming. **Really** new and am trying to get the "outputLabel" to fade in when I press the "quoteButtonTapped" button. I have tried to set the alpha to 0.0 and then with a delay to alpha 1.0 but

self.outputLabel.alpha does not work.

Wow! I am perhaps missing something really basic here but the "quoteButtonTapped" does select a random quotation from an array and it's reference label, but how can I get the label text to fade in?

I included code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var borderImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewWindow: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var referenceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func quoteButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        scrollViewWindow.contentSize.height = 800
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

func displayCurrentScripture() {

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    let QuoteString = quotes.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)
    let ReferenceString = references.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)

    self.outputLabel.text = QuoteString as? String
    self.referenceLabel.text = ReferenceString as? String
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

        UILabel.referenceLabel..
    }

    displayCurrentScripture()
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code you set the alpha

Comment: u can hide label by `label.hidden - true`

Comment: Thank You. I tried to enter the code but normally when you type in self.outputLabel.typing an "a" would give a list of options but .alpha was not one of the list. Typed it in anyway but it did not result in any change when run.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayCurrentScripture();
        }

func displayCurrentScripture() {

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    let QuoteString = quotes.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)
    let ReferenceString = references.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)


    self.outputLabel.alpha = 0.0
    self.referenceLabel.alpha = 0.0

    self.outputLabel.text = QuoteString as? String
    self.referenceLabel.text = ReferenceString as? String

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.outputLabel.alpha = 1.0
            self.referenceLabel.alpha = 1.0
        });

    }
```